# Compute 30000 Digits of Pi (π), as Fast as Possible

Tags: math, fastest-code

Compute 30000 digits of the mathematical constant π, with the fastest code.

Implement in any computer programming language that I can run in my 64 bit Linux machine. You should provide your compiler optimization options if any. I am ready to install a new compiler or language runtime to run your code, given that I am not spending any money.

The code that finishes calculation and prints the output in the shortest time wins! I will measure the running time with the `time` command.

note 1: The program should be single threaded.
note 2: With 3.14, the number of digits is 3; with 3.1415, 5, and so on.
note 3: Hard coding π is not allowed.
note 4: Now you can use any number form in your code, not only integer.
note 5: Your output, which should be in decimal digits, need not contain the `.`. Just print out the numbers.
note 6: Your last digit should **not** be rounded up. If the next digit after the last is 5 or more, you should <s>round up your last digit</s> still leave the last digit as is.

*Since this question was marked as duplicate, to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47912/calculate-%CF%80-with-quadratic-convergence) question. I should explain that this is a 'fastest-code' question not 'code-golf' and thus not a dupliate. The 'code-golf' answers are not well suited as an answer to this question; they are not the 'fastest'.*

Comment: @trichoplax After thinking about a while with your comment, I decided to change my mind. Yes, since this is computing the 'digits', rounding up seems incorrect. I changed note 6.

Comment: Even before that edit, your question seemed clearly defined, so I'm not sure why there was a downvote. +1

Comment: This isn't an *exact* duplicate of the quadratic convergence on pi question, but it's close enough that IMO it's a dupe.

Comment: Are you going to redirect the output to /dev/null for measuring the time? I have a feeling that output might take much longer than the actual calculation even then, but it would be even worse if it's actually printed to a terminal.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Why is this marked as a duplicate? This question is not 'code-golf'.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Do you think 30000 digits is too less for a fast program?

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/777/194

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes so the 'code-golf' answers are not competitive answers to this question.

Comment: "I think for the new challenge to qualify as a duplicate, those old answers also have to be competitive." Code-golf answers **ARE** competitive for this question, since the linked question ALSO required fast run-time (quadratic convergence). Thus each answer in that question will ALSO be fast, and therefore competitive.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the problem, so I don't have a precise idea of what the runtime will be. But considering the links to algorithms with quadratic convergence, it could be very short. And increasing the number of digits might not help the ratio between output and calculation. We'll see the results, I guess.

Comment: Although this is a duplicate, I had a python solution that ran in 0.7 s and a C++ rewrite (that's not working for some reason now) that was about 25% faster

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate? It's actually a very different goal. The other question was to produce the shortest code; this question is to produce the fastest code. I think it is a mistake to mark this as a duplicate — especially since the question is clearly marked as `fastest-code`.

Comment: Also, I have a solution that runs in about 2.3 seconds that I'd like to post.

Comment: @ToddLehman Comment with a link to the code and we can at least look at it.

Comment: @xiver77 Python 2 with gmpy2 (Chudnovsky alg): http://codepad.org/Yh0fWAKZ. Runtime for 30000 digits is negligible.

Comment: I have a C++ program that does it in zero time (it takes a long time to compile though...)  Are you including the time to compile the program?

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 (Spigot Algorithm)

This is just Jeremy Gibbon's [algorithm](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf) implemented in python. Definitely will be faster once someone else implements this in another language. Other methods might be faster too since I started working on this when the rules stated that I could only use integers. I originally tried doing this without string conversion and joining, but it was actually slower..

```python
def p():
 q,r,t,j=1,180,60,2
 while True:
    u,y=3*(3*j+1)*(3*j+2),(q*(27*j-12)+5*r)//(5*t);yield y;q,r,t,j=10*q*j*(2*j-1),10*u*(q*(5*j-2)+r-y*t),t*u,j+1
p=p()
print''.join(str(p.next())for x in[1]*30000)
```

Completes on my work machine in about 53 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was reading that PDF after searching for algorithms (without seeing your link to it), and I was having a hard time reading the Haskell syntax. I'm glad I can see it now in a language I can understand.

Comment: Also, since this isn't code-golf, don't feel like you need to cram the internal of the `while` onto one line. And, you can use `/` instead of `//` since this is Python 2, though you can leave it for readability.

Comment: @mbomb007 Yeah, I realized I didn't need to golf it, it just sort of happened, haha.

Comment: Here it is golfed more (just for fun): http://ideone.com/lOhcxB . Run it with a number < 30000 if you want to see output (I used 300).